# Accessing executables without going to file location on command line

Tags: windows-7, command-line

In my school Unix servers, I can run certain programs on the command line without going to the file where they are located. For example,

```
shell> java filename
```

would run the file with java. The home-computer I use has Windows on it, and I was wondering if I could do something similar on the command line. Right not, I have to go to the path location of the executable, and type in the name of the executable to run it.

```
C:\longpath> java filename
```

Is it possible to access java (or any other program for that matter) without going to its file location via the Windows command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the path to your program to the `path` environment variable. Then you can access files in that directory from anywhere in command-prompts that you open after changing the variable.

1. Press <kbd>⊞Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `systempropertiesadvanced` and click `[OK]`
3. Click `[Environment Variables]`
4. Modify the `path` variable (use the top half for just the current user; the bottom half for all users):

   - If the `path` variable exists:

     1. Select it and click `[Edit]`
     2. Press <kbd>End</kbd> to go to the end of the variable
     3. Press <kbd>;</kbd> and type or paste the path
     4. Click `[OK]` to accept and close out open dialog boxes
   - If the `path` variable doesn’t already exist:

     1. Click `[New]`
     2. Enter `Path` for the name
     3. Enter the path for the value
     4. Click `[OK]` to accept and close out open dialog boxes

Caveats:

- Delimit multiple paths with `;` (e.g., `c:\foo;c:\bar;c:\baz`)
- Be careful not to mess up any existing paths or you can cause Windows to malfunction

  - You can copy the existing path to a text-editor like Notepad and make your changes there before copying it back to the dialog when you are happy; this is advisable because the edit field in the dialog is small, so you cannot see the whole thing like you can in Notepad (especially if you enable word-wrap)
- The changes only apply to *new* command-prompts, so you’ll have to close existing ones and open a new one